# Commutativity of a product of self-adjoint matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have self-adjoint matrices A and B such that $AB-BA \neq 0$.
Also, we know that the following is true (not sure if this is relevant)

1. $A^2 \neq A$.
2. $A^2 \neq I$.
3. $\forall \ k \in N, \exists \ p \in N$ s.t. $A^{2k} = pA^2$.
4. $\forall \ k \in N, \exists \ q \in N$ s.t. $A^{2k+1} = qA$.

My numerical experiments show that $A^2BA - ABA^2 = 0$, but I don't know if this holds for any symmetric $A$ and $B$ with aforementioned properties or I just got "lucky" matrices that cancel out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample:
$$
A=\pmatrix{1\\ &-1\\ &&0}\ \text{ and }\ B=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1\\ &&0}.
$$
It is easy to verify that $AB\ne BA,\,A^2=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,0)\notin\{A,I\},\,A^{2k}=A^2$ and $A^{2k+1}=A$. However, $A^2BA-ABA^2=BA-AB\ne0$.